# Javascript Can't use array content as array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I trird to run the js code, it always said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined" for

```
deployedID.push(data[j]._id);
```

So after some thinking, I believe the problem lies in

```
var j = deploy[i];
```

Is there any way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Below is the complete code:

```
    var deploy = [];
    var deployedID = [];
    var deployedename = [];
    var deployedoname = [];
    var deployedrank = [];

function popularizeTable(){
    $.get("/SSS/getlist", function(data){
        deploy = randomunique(data.length ,100);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            var j = deploy[i];
            deployedID.push(data[j]._id);
            deployedename.push(data[j].ename);
            deployedoname.push(data[j].oname);
            deployedrank.push(data[j].rank);
        }
        var str = " ";
        var k = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            str += "<tr>";
            for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){            
                str += "<td><section id=\"" + deployedID[k] + "\" class=\"container\"><div class=\"card\">"
                str += "<figure class=\"front\"><img src=\"images/back.jpg\"></figure>";
                str += "<figure class=\"back\"><img src=\"images/Clear/" + deployedename[k] + "/001.jpg\"></figure></div></td></section>";
                k++;
            } 
            str += "</tr>";     
        }
        $("#table").append(str);
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    popularizeTable();
    $(document).on("mouseover", ".card", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("flipped")});
});

function randomunique(max, num){
    var uniquelist = [];
    for (var j = uniquelist.length; j < num; j++){
        var i = parseInt(Math.random() * (max - 1) + 1);
        if (uniquelist.indexOf(i) == -1){
            uniquelist.push(i);
        }
    }
    return uniquelist;
}
```

Comment: yeah make sure that `data[j]` exists

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(data);`? Are you sure that your response is parsed as JSON?

Comment: @Thomas is correct - your issue is that `data[j]` doesn't exist. I see where you define a private variable `j` but fail to see where you associate that with the `data` variable. I see it's being passed into your `$.get()` function, but don't see the association.

Comment: `randomunique` appears to be creating an array of random, distinct numbers. You are then using one of those numbers as a property or index for the `data` that comes back from your `GET` request. Since the random, distinct numbers must be within a range, I guess you know they'd be somewhere between 1-100 (max). Are you sure the `data` that you are returning is an array with that many indices, or an object with those properties? What is the structure of `data`? Also, this is a fairly inefficient way to generate an array of numbers 1-100 in random order.

Comment: @Thomas data should have 166 entries and deploy should contain 100 distinct numbers ranging between 0 to 165. Therefore, data[j] should exist.

Comment: @crush I am sure the data returning have 166 such indices. Checked by console.log(data[165]._id), data[165]._id does exist. Data is a JSON string that has 166 entries containg _id, ename, oname, rank. What you described is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user3796223 although the `key` exist, there is no guarantee that the corresponding `value` is defined as an object with the `property` `"_id"`

Comment: @Thomas The error indicates that `data[j]` is undefined, though. So, whether `_id` exists or not doesn't matter at this point. Without seeing `data`, I'm not sure we can help further at this point.

Comment: To ALL: problems solved... It turned out that I did not generate 100 numbers as I expected in the original code... I have made the adjustment and it works now. Thank you all for helping. Much appreciated!